# Google Chrome on Ubuntu 17.04 Runs Extremely Slow

Tags: google-chrome

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 as my only operating system on my laptop which previously came with Windows 10 installed. I had enough with windows for various reasons and decided to use Ubuntu and I love it. However, I use google chrome as my web browser, and it is unbelievably slow. It takes a solid 11 seconds to just switch tabs. When I was running windows 10 on my same laptop and using chrome, it was completely fine and I had no performance issues with it. What is causing chrome to run so slowly? (I only have about 2 tabs open at once and it still runs at the same slow speed) How can I fix this issue? I have already tried chromium and it still runs amazingly slow, and I am not switching web browsers.

Comment: When running chrome check `shift+esc` to see which tab (if any) takes most of the cpu power, You can also check `htop` in command line to see if other program takes the cpu power.

Comment: That’s not what my question is asking. I already did that and I am already aware that chrome is taking up a ton of RAM on Ubuntu, but on windows 10 i could have 11 tabs open at once and it would be working completely fine

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Both Chrome & FireFox are REALLY slow although DNS responds quickly and ping is good. I have no idea what is going on here but I suspect it has something to do with TCP IPv6.